# Will an automated access macro run if a database is opened in read only mode?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am designing a macro to run a set of queries on launching of a database, I am the only person that will access it normally, others will open it as read only. Will the macro's run when others open it as read only?

Comment: Do those queries alter data in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the macro's run when others open it as read only?

Yes, the macro(s) will run, unless the user holds the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down to bypass the startup actions as they open the database (and there is a way to disable that if necessary).